# What should I subclass to get custom controls?

Tags: cocoa, user-interface, subclassing

I'm using Alfred on mac. It's some kind of launcher that helps opening applications and documents faster.
I've been wondering how they did their custom controls. I don't know if they subclassed an NSView or NSTextField. Here is a screenshot. [image: Alfred ui]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might want to watch WWDC 2010 Session 141 - Crafting Custom Cocoa Views. Registered ADC developers (including free accounts) can download it from iTunes U.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I would guess that they subclassed NSTextField for the input.  The search results could be based on NSView.  You should subclass the control that gives you the features that you need, allowing you to build upon them. The less functionality you have to reimplement, the better!

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. How can you be sure they didn't subclass NSTextFieldCell?